# Storing multiple videos in one folder - bad idea?

Tags: php, file, video, upload

My question is, is it a bad idea to store multiple videos in one folder?

I have created a video uploader script, but it doesn't save each video in a seperate folder, it saves all of them in one folder (each with a different hashed video name).

```
- videos folder
    - e0d123e5f316bef78bfdf5a008837577
    - 35d91262b3c3ec8841b54169588c97f7
    - cc273fe9d442850fa18c31c88c823e07
```

Is this a bad idea? Could this lead to any problems? What are the pros and cons of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this IS a problem once you have few thousands files in that directory. Some operating systems choke when there are that many files in one folder.

I also remember one case where a FTP server refused to show more than 4000 files in a directory listing.

One solution is to organize your files like this:

```
- videos folder
 - e
  - e0d123e5f316bef78bfdf5a008837577
 - 3
  - 35d91262b3c3ec8841b54169588c97f7
 - c
  - cc273fe9d442850fa18c31c88c823e07
```

This gives you max 16 folders below videos folder. If you still end up with too many files in the sub-directory then use another level:

```
- videos folder
 - e
  - e0
   - e0d123e5f316bef78bfdf5a008837577
 - 3
  - 35
   - 35d91262b3c3ec8841b54169588c97f7
 - c
  - cc
   - cc273fe9d442850fa18c31c88c823e07
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many videos there will be. File systems have limits on the number of files in a single folder. Once you get close to that limit or over it you will experience all sorts of trouble. The biggest of which will be massive slowdowns when accessing the files (videos).

Figure out what the limit for your file system is and then decide if you need to put the videos into sub folders.

Answer (score 2):

It could lead to problems if there is a collision, which becomes increasingly likely as the amount of videos increases. However, this in itself is not bad practice (especially if you have a small number of videos); why would you need to split the videos into separate folders if each video is one file?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different thoughts about this. I think it really depends on the scale of your website. What do you expect it to be? If it is used as an internal video sharing site where you know there will only be 10 members because you chose them to be members, I don't see any problems. But when you are going to have a billion members like Youtube does, consider the consequences.

Maybe this article can help you in some way: http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture